# Convert python dictionary to table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'SERVICE_METHOD-2B632733DAAE1C17': ['getCompanies', [[1569555000000, 1241.0]], [[1569555000000, 4290064.489927478]]], 'SERVICE_METHOD-294613F34334F4B4': ['verifyOtp', [[1569555000000, 366.0]], [[1569555000000, 5553469.797814208]]]}
```

I want this in a table format like this:

```
Service_Method_Name Service_Method_ID   Timestamp   Count   Response
verifyOtp   SERVICE_METHOD-294613F34334F4B4 1569555000000   366 5553469.79
getCompanies    SERVICE_METHOD-2B632733DAAE1C17 1569555000000   1241    4290064.49
```

This is what I have done so far..

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(aaa)

for i in dict1 : 
    aaa = [i, (dict1[i][0]), (dict1[i][1][0][0]), (dict1[i][1][0][1]), (dict1[i][2][0][1])]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(aaa)

print(df)
```

Am getting the following output

```
                                 0
0  SERVICE_METHOD-294613F34334F4B4
1                        verifyOtp
2                    1569555000000
3                              366
4                      5.55347e+06
```

How to get all the values in the table format mentioned above?

Comment: You can try this. First define a dict `new_dict = {'service_method_name':[],'service_method_id':[],'Timestamp':[],'Count':[],'Response':[]}` and then iterate over your dictionary and append the values. Lastly, turn that new dictionary into a dataframe:
 `for i in dict1:
 new_dict['service_method_name'].append(dict1[i][0])
 new_dict['service_method_id'].append(i)
 new_dict['Timestamp'].append(dict1[i][1][0][0]) #timestamp
 new_dict['Count'].append(dict1[i][1][0][1]) #Count
 new_dict['Response'].append(str(dict1[i][2][0][1])) #response
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a mistake in your code - you've been overwriting `aaa` variable on every loop iteration, so data from previous iteration was lost.

To make a proper conversion you, for example, need to store data in list of lists (which is named `lst` in below code):

```
import pandas as pd 

dict1 = {'SERVICE_METHOD-2B632733DAAE1C17': ['getCompanies', [[1569555000000, 1241.0]], [[1569555000000, 4290064.489927478]]], 'SERVICE_METHOD-294613F34334F4B4': ['verifyOtp', [[1569555000000, 366.0]], [[1569555000000, 5553469.797814208]]]}

lst = []
for i in dict1 : 
    lst.append([i, (dict1[i][0]), (dict1[i][1][0][0]), (dict1[i][1][0][1]), (dict1[i][2][0][1])])

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['Service_Method_ID', 'Service_Method_Name', 'Timestamp', 'Count', 'Response']

print(df)
```